# how to prove the only difference between antidrivaties of a function is in their constants?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, alternative-proof

how to prove

"***If  `F` is an antiderivative of  `f`  on an interval `I` , then the most general
antiderivative of `f` on `I` is
`F(x)+C`***"

it means there does not exist any functions other than F(x)+C group which can be the answer to the 
problem , right?

i can think of proving it by using fundemental theorem of calculus part 2 like :

suppose we have another group of function called `g(x)+c` where `g(x)` is not equal to `F(x)`
and `g'(x) = f(x)` then we get to contradiction when we try to calculate the definite integral of `f(x)` from a to b

because    `g(b)-g(a)`  is not necessarily equal to `F(b)-F(a)`

so we have two values for one area !

but are there any other ways to prove it ?

Comment: The point is that the two "groups" (as you say) are the same set and $\,g(b)-g(a)=F(b)-F(a)$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe your proof is correct.

Here's a proof that will work: suppose that $F$ and $G$ are two antiderivatives of $f$.  It follows that
$$
G'(x) - F'(x) = f(x) - f(x) = 0 \implies\\
[G - F]'(x) = 0
$$
That is, the function $G(x) - F(x)$ has a derivative of $0$.  Since the only functions whose derivative are zero (on an interval) are constant functions, we have
$$
G(x) - F(x) = C \implies\\
G(x) = F(x) + C
$$
That is, any antiderivative $G(x)$ of $f(x)$ has the form $F(x) + C$.

Comment: i think your proof is right but why is mine wrong?

Comment: You say: "suppose we have another group of function called $g(x)+c$ where $g(x)$ is not equal to $F(x)$ and $g'(x) = f(x)$".  What if $g(x) = F(x) + 2$? You say: "$g(b)-g(a)$ is not necessarily equal to $F(b)-F(a)$". But can you prove that this difference is necessarily not equal to $F(b) - F(a)$?